# How do I run a block of test code more than once?

Tags: ruby, loops, yield, block

I'm building the Test-First-Teaching performance_monitor and can get to the fifth test but then it fails.

Why is my block only running once?

This is my code:

```
require "time"
t = Time.now
def measure x=0
start = Time.now
    yield x 
endt = Time.now - start
    end
measure(4){ |x| x.times do Time.now - t end}
```

This is the error:

```
*Error____
Performance Monitor
  takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block
  takes exactly 0 seconds to run an empty block (with stubs)
  takes about 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second
  takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)
  runs a block N times (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Performance Monitor runs a block N times
     Failure/Error: n.should == 4
       expected: 4
            got: 1 (using ==)
```

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial you're following?  It's a little hard to tell what's supposed to be happening from just the above.

Comment: https://github.com/ultrasaurus/test-first-teaching/tree/master/learn_ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it like this:  Your `measure` method is the one that's in charge of making sure the block that gets passed to it is run the correct number of times.  So the block you pass to `measure` should only include the code that should be run in a *single* iteration.

For a bare-bones example (theme shamelessly ripped from Gary Bernhardt's ["WAT"](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) talk):

```
def repeat_x_times(x)
    # This runs the passed block x times:
    x.times do
        yield
    end
end

repeat_x_times(16) do
    # This is what should happen in a single iteration:
    puts 0.0 / 0.0
end

puts 'Batman!'
```

The other cool thing about blocks is that you can always access the variables in the same scope as the block (usually local variables), regardless of where the yield happens:

```
i = 3
4.times {i += 1} # We can still get to i!
puts i           # Prints "7"
```

Combining the two concepts for a slightly more involved example:

```
array = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
sum = 0
array.each do |item|
    # In the first iteration, item is 3; in the second it's 6, and so on:
    sum += item
end
puts sum
```

Now, I know I haven't answered your question directly, but it sounds like you're learning Ruby, so hopefully this is more useful than a cut-n-paste...  Anyway, just play around with this until you get it, and pretty soon you'll be wishing all languages had such a useful feature!

Comment: Awesome answer! I like how you led me to what I was looking for and didnt just fix it! Ill post the code I used to fix it after work. Probably shouldn't be coding or posting here ha.

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with :

```
    require "time"

    def measure (x=1)
        elapsed = 0
        x.times do
        start = Time.now
        yield
        endt = Time.now
        elapsed += endt - start
   end
   elapsed / x
   if elapsed < 1 
        time = "milliseconds"
   else
        time = "seconds"

    end
    puts "We ran this block #{x} times \nand it took #{elapsed} #{time}"
    end

    measure(50000){puts "Run a block" }
```